# Directing requests to instance on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to group certain requests togeather based on their url ensuring that similar requests go to the same instance?

E.g.
There are multiple instances for my app engine

myurl.com?foo=abc // Multiple people putting in this url will all go to the same instance

myurl.com // I don't care which one this goes

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding your questions correctly, you want to make a load balancing based on the request parameters on the URL?

Comment: Yes basically. A bit more context - my program deals with in-mem handling that I realize now fails if there are multiple insances. I could rewrite code by I would prefer to see if this is an option.

Comment: Got it, is your site an API or a web page?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Considering the instances in AppEngine are ephemeral, I dont think it's a good approach.

Comment: Agree with GAEfan, However if your app is not going to have a lot of traffic you can use multiple services within your app and use manual scaling to one instance and this in theory will keep requests to the same service in the same instance. Not recommended because manual scaling can cause othernissues if your traffic scales

Comment: Ok, it was more wondering if this was a reasonable approach. I was looking though Google's examples and saw their in-mem chat app and they used the "keep to 1 instance" approach and was wondering if this approach could be scaled. Or if you need to completely rewrite that app.

Comment: @Emmanuel web-page. It involves sockets and keeping multiple users up-to date

Comment: From what you are describing, you just need the people to be in the same chatroom somehow, correct? Then  you dont really care about the instance they are about. The instances can use shared resources (eg. Memcache, Redis, DataStore etc), and each chatroom will obtain a specific collection based on the `?foo=abc`.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Ok thank you. I will take a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can control which `instance` handles a url pattern.

If you want to send certain urls to a certain `service`, what you want is a `dispatch.yaml`, which does exactly that.  You can use regex to tailor how you want. With some strategy, you could match urls with (groups of) instances, though they would be in separate services.  If your site doesn't get a lot of traffic, you could essentially have one instance per service, and accomplish what you want.

```
dispatch:
# don't forget: gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml   after changes !!!

- url: "*/some/high/memory/urls/*"  
  service: my_high_memory_service

- url: "*/some/fast/cpu/url"  
  service: my_fast_cpu_service
  
- url: "*/.*"
  service: default
```

More at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml

Comment: This seems like it might be closest to what I want, thank you